# Does spring boot actuator no longer have pause endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

[Spring Boot 2.6.6 - Actuator API Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/actuator-api/htmlsingle/)

I checked the above link and unable to find the `/actuator/pause` endpoint. I was not sure if it was my app that was causing the issue, so I created a new MVP from spring initializer and even then pause endpoint is not there.

I remember that there used to be a POST endpoint `/actuator/pause`, but how do I enable this on newer versions of Spring Boot(2.6.6 above)?

The below is my MVP's code.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**application.yml**

```yaml
management:
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'
  endpoint:
    pause.enabled: true
    restart.enabled: true
    resume.enabled: true
    shutdown.enabled: true
```

And once I start the app and hit

`curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/actuator/pause'`, its sending 404.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:3.1.1
```

You can see that `RestartEndpoint` and
`RestartEndpoint.PauseEndpoint` classes actually are defined in this package.

Obviously you should change the `application.yml` like this:

```
management:
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'
  endpoint:
    pause:
      enabled: true
    restart:
      enabled: true
```

Comment: But its not doing anything? It always returns true and then if I hit `/actuator/health` it always says `UP`. So essentially `actuator/pause` endpoint is not working.

Comment: @theprogrammer it works, you should create some classes that implement `PauseHandler` interface and annotate it with `@Component` for example.

Comment: Can you add those code snippets? In previous versions, I just had to add some properties in application.yml and it worked without any code changes.

Comment: @theprogrammer could you specify which version? thanks.

Comment: The previous Spring Boot version where its working for me is `2.1.2.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that [Spring Cloud Commons](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-commons#overview) is included in your project dependencies, since it looks like that's the library that supplies the `actuator/pause` endpoint (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#endpoints).

As the documentation additionally notes:

> If you disable the /actuator/restart endpoint then the /actuator/pause and /actuator/resume endpoints will also be disabled since they are just a special case of /actuator/restart.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to support it by yourself.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/health")
public class HealthController implements HealthIndicator {

    private Health health = Health.up().build();

    @RequestMapping("/pause")
    @ResponseBody
    public String pause() {
        health = Health.down().build();
        return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/start")
    @ResponseBody
    public String start() {
        health = Health.up().build();
        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return health;
    }

}
```